VBA Changing Value from drop down to Validation List brings all previous choices with comma separated values on list
In effort to manipulate with vba data validation, my excel application is now having the following strange behavior.
I set data validation to allow a list of a few choices. I initially choose chose one option from the drop down list. I then go the same cell and chose another option.
In cell appears previous choice and the current choice with a comma between them.
At this moment I don't now how to solve it! 

Press Alt+F11 to open the VBE (Visual Basic for Applications) window and check if there is any VBA code in your file.
